# Subject-Verb Agreement: "A selection of"

Tags: verb-agreement

I was okay with the following sentence the first time I read it:

"...a selection of films that explore..."

Then I realized that the subject of this sentence is probably "a selection" and not "films". However, "...a selection of films that explore**s**" sounds klunky to me.

Which is correct (or more correct)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Search of Agreement](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/274367/in-search-of-agreement)

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/274367/in-search-of-agreement because the complete sentence of the example in the other post brings out the validity of both forms and the distinction between them more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

Both versions could be correct.

> A selection of films that explore...

Here, there is a selection of films, each of which explores something. *Explore* matches the plural *films.*

> A selection of films that explores...

Here, there is a selection of films, but those films are taken together and it is the selection which explores. *Explores* matches the singular *selection.*

Both are grammatical, but the first seems more likely to me as the selection was probably made on the basis of each film's exploration of the subject.

Answer (score 0):

The restrictive clause "that explore" modifies "films," so "that" refers to the same plural noun, thus must itself be plural, and must therefore take a plural verb.  "Explore" is correct.  Had the sentence read

> ... a selection of films explores

then explores would have been the verb in the clause with "selection," a singular noun, as its subject.  And in that case "explores" would have been correct.

Answer (score 0):

I believe both choices are OK , if you are referring to selection of films  as a singular noun ( one selection ) which is correct ,  the verb needs to be " explores "  but if you are using selection of films  as a collective noun the verb can be either "explore " or " explores " . In all cases , selection is the subject that needs to agree with the verb